# Java BufferedReader, how to preserve new lines?

Tags: java, android

How to preserve new lines in this example? I need read inputStream keeping the line breaks.

**"inputStream"** comes from **HttpURLConnection**

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, charset));

String line;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(line);
}
```

That code is executed under android platform.

Comment: Just append a "\n" after you append the line. Simple workaround

Comment: Just add them manually with `stringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"))`

Comment: Comments are not the place for answering questions. Answers are the place for that.

Comment: Oh, it comes from a server. So you may have multiple line breaks and what not. So, read it byte-by-byte using `bufferedReader.read()`.

Comment: result += line+"/n"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a new line to the string builder:

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(line);
    stringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

Which would put a line break after each line you append to the string

Comment: Or `System.lineSeparator()`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at StringJoiner which uses a StringBuilder under the covers

[String Joiner docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(System.lineSeparator());

while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    sj.add(line);
}
```